# Instagram Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, instagram

I was wondering how to achieve Instagram Real-Time post updates similar to this page:

http://www.flashtat.com/

It's in the section labeled: SHINE ON, FLASHIONISTAS!

I see that it's Javascript but is it custom coded or can I find the Javascript code and just modify it to a different Instagram account?

Cheers.

Comment: is there a certain aspect of the feed thing that you want to replicate? or just re-use the whole thing?

Comment: Hi - I'd like to have the feed connected to an instagram account so that whenever I take a picture and post it onto instagram - it also updates on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Never used them by myself but friend of mine done similar things with the following:

Caman.js

Filereader.js

jQuery Mousewheel

Answer (score 0):

From the Instagram [Real - Time API](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/?hl=en):

> Real-time photo updates provide your application with instant notifications of new photos as they are posted on Instagram.